# Laravel Query Not work with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to get my query result with where condition . My current query is

```
$last_query     = DB::table('user_matchs')->where('matched_user_id', '=', $UserId)->where('status','=','friend')->lists('user_id');
$mid_query      = DB::table('user_matchs')->where('user_id', '=', $UserId)->lists('matched_user_id');

$query = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', '!=', $UserId)
        ->whereNotIn('id',$mid_query)
        ->whereNotIn('id',$last_query);  

$getchat_details = DB::table('preferences')->where('UserId', $UserId)->first();

if($getchat_details->ShowMan == 'true')
 { 
    $query->where('gender', '=', 'male');
}
else  { 
    $query->where('gender', '=', 'female');      
 }  

    $users = $query->get();

    return Response::json($users );


    }
```

In my query where condition not work which added using if else conditon

Comment: When you say it's not working, what exactly is not working? if you do `var_dump($query->toSql());` just before `$users = $query->get();` what does it output? Does it have the where condition added or not?

Comment: use `$query->orWhere(` instead of `$query->where(`

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the gender to query for beforehand.

```
if($getchat_details->ShowMan == 'true') { 
    $gender = 'male';
} else { 
    $gender = 'female';
}

$query = DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', '!=', $UserId)
    ->where('gender', $gender)
    ->whereNotIn('id',$mid_query)
    ->whereNotIn('id',$last_query);
```

Comment: No. It's not needed to assign the result of a `where()` call to `$query`. Calling the method changes the instance itself. `$this` is only returned to make it easily chainable.

Comment: @lukasgeiter You're right, I removed the non-working solution.